# Tab Name already exists or has been previously used

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, tab

I had one custom `visualforce` page tab in our salesforce account and that is a part of the manage package too. I removed that visualforce page tab and now trying to create with the same name and I am getting following error.

[image]

I tried to reach to the saelsforce support team but hey are asking us to have the `premier support`

> Developer Support (which encompasses custom code, authentication, and
> integration issues) is available to customers and partners with
> Premier Success plans. If you wish to upgrade to Premier Support
> please contact your Account Executive. Our records indicate that your
> account is entitled to Standard Support and therefore we need to close
> this case and direct you to our Developer boards

We are the ISV partners but not sure why they asking us to get the premier support here. However, is there any way to use the same name here for the visual force page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same value as before for ‘Tab Label’, e.g. ‘My Page’, but edit the value for ‘Tab Name’ to e.g. ‘MyPageCustom’.